# Create table/list and store it - what are my options?

Tags: listbox, tabular

I need something like this: http://listjs.com/examples/add-edit-remove
That means: a single page with a table and some fixed columns and users can add rows.

Since list.js is Javascript, it is not persistent across machines. But I am not very experienced in web technologies so I wonder what are my options here to store the informations?

Is a database needed? Seems like a bit overkill to me, I only need a table where some users can add a row in a dead simple way (like the example above).
Can I store the table into a file and render a HTML table from it?
Are there any prepackaged solutions which I can extend to my needs? PHP, Python, Ruby, Frameworks?

I was searching around for grocery-lists, to-do-lists and the like, I also considered installing a wiki but that is overkill to. This list should get deleted every day and would be used by maybe 5-6 people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like http://handsontable.com/ is exactly what I am looking for. There is a "load and save" example on their Github page which uses SQLite.